# Concatenating strings with variables inside a javascript array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I understand that this probably isn't something I should be making a habit of. But I was trying to concat a variable to a string that's stored in as a Javascript array property.

For instance I have:

```
var form = {
    'var1' : 'has a value here',
    'array' : [
        [ 'some text', 'some more text' ],
        [ 'second line of text', 'second entry ' + form.var1]
    ]
};
alert( form.array[1][1] );
```

That results in an alert displaying 'undefined'.

If I instead do this:

```
var var1 = 'has a value here';
var form = {
    'array' : [
        [ 'some text', 'some more text' ],
        [ 'second line of text', 'second entry ' + var1 ]
    ]
};
alert( form.array[1][1] );
```

The string is defined and displays properly.

Is there a way I can store that value under the 'form' object and still get the result I want? I'm presuming 'no'. But I figured I'd ask. (This is a difficult question to google. :P)

Comment: Yea, it was a typo. Fixed, thanks. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare it in two parts:

```
var form = {
    'var1' : 'has a value here'
};

form['array'] = [
    [ 'some text', 'some more text' ],
    [ 'second line of text', 'second entry ' + form.var1]
];

alert( form.array[1][1] );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it inside the object literal (before finishing the object expression, the `form` is undefined.), but you could do it outside.

```
var form = {
    'var1' : 'has a value here',
    'array' : [
        [ 'some text', 'some more text' ],
        [ 'second line of text', 'second entry ']
    ]
};

form.array[1][1] += form.var1;
alert( form.array[1][1] );​
```

Comment: dbaseman has the answer more akin to what I was looking for; but this is yet another solution I didn't think of. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised you even reach the alert statement.  Your code would fail as soon as it hits `form.var1` since form is not defined.  One way to get to that is to define them separately. Like so

```
var form = {};
   form.var1 = 'has a value here';
   form.array =   [
      [ 'some text', 'some more text' ],
      [ 'second line of text', 'second entry ' + form.var1]
   ];
```

Comment: @Squish I meant not declared within the scope of the object, it refers to the same object